# Testing equality of tibbles with list-columns or nested data.frame

Tags: r, equality, testthat

Tibbles (from the `tidyverse`) can contain list-columns, which is useful to contain e.g. nested dataframes or objects not traditionally found in a data.frame.

Here is an example:

```r
library("dplyr")

nested_df <-
      iris %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      tidyr::nest() %>%
      mutate(model = purrr::map(data, lm, formula = Sepal.Length ~ .))

nested_df
#  # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Species    data              model   
#   <fct>      <list>            <list>  
# 1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>
# 2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>
# 3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>
```

I am writing some tests with `testthat`: **how do I test equality between such data.frames?**

`testthat::expect_equal` does not work because `all.equal` and `dplyr::all_equal` both fail:

```r
all.equal(nested_df, nested_df)
# Error in equal_data_frame(target, current, ignore_col_order = ignore_col_order,  : 
#  Can't join on 'data' x 'data' because of incompatible types (list / list)
```

I considered using `testthat::expect_true(identical(...))`, but it is often too strict. For example, defining the exact same `nested_df2` is not enough to pass `identical` because the `.Environment` attribute of the `terms` embedded in the `lm` model is different, although the models are equal and pass `all.equal`.

```r
identical(nested_df, nested_df2)
# [1] FALSE
identical(nested_df$model, nested_df2$model, ignore.environment = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE
all.equal(nested_df$model, nested_df2$model, tolerance = 0)
# [1] TRUE
```

How can I test equality of tibbles with list-columns like `nested_df`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kinda blunt approach, but it seems to work on your example:

```
all.equal.list(nested_df, nested_df)

# [1] TRUE

all.equal.list(nested_df, mutate(nested_df, Species = sample(Species)))

# [1] "Component “Species”: 2 string mismatches"
```

Comment: Works great on all my tests as well - thanks! I'll leave the question opened a bit longer in case someone else has something to contribute.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @utubun 's answer, you can wrap all.equal.list in a testthat-like `expect_*` function:

```
expect_equal_tbl <- function(object, expected, ..., info = NULL) {
  act <- testthat::quasi_label(rlang::enquo(object), arg = "object")
  exp <- testthat::quasi_label(rlang::enquo(expected), arg = "expected")

  # all.equal.list is slightly problematic: it returns TRUE for match, and
  # returns a character vector when differences are observed. We extract
  # both a match-indicator and a failure message

  diffs <- all.equal.list(object, expected, ...)
  has_diff <- if (is.logical(diffs)) diffs else FALSE
  diff_msg <- paste(diffs, collapse = "\n")

  testthat::expect(
    has_diff,
    failure_message = sprintf(
      "%s not equal to %s.\n%s", act$lab, exp$lab, diff_msg
    ),
    info = info
  )

  invisible(act$val)
}
```

```
expect_equal_tbl(nested_df, nested_df, info = "YAY!")
```

```
expect_equal_tbl(nested_df, nested_df[1, ], info = "FAIL!")
 Error: `nested_df` not equal to nested_df[1, ].
Attributes: < Component “row.names”: Numeric: lengths (3, 1) differ >
Component “Species”: Lengths: 3, 1
Component “Species”: Lengths (3, 1) differ (string compare on first 1)
Component “data”: Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components
Component “model”: Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components
FAIL!
```

Comment: That's nice! If you want to make it really comprehensive, you also need to handle grouped df correctly. Consider `gdf <- group_by(iris, Species)`. Then you get an error with `expect_equal_tbl(gdf, gdf)`. I personally have had to resort to something like: `equality_fun  <- if ("grouped_df" %in% class(obj)) all.equal.grouped_df else all.equal.list` where `all.equal.grouped_df` checks that both the data (ungrouped) and the groups match. Not very elegant. It would be nice to have a robust `expect_equal_tbl` function!

Comment: Also just FYI you can use `rlang::is_true` to check the result of `all.equal.*` functions. Or even better use `testthat::expect_true` directly instead of `testthat::expect`. `expect_true` only passes if the result if exactly identical to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks, but I probably wouldn't use `is_true` because there's a simple workaround in base that's only one extra line of code. I hadn't considered grouped dfs when writing the above.

Comment: @asac could you confirm where `all.equal.grouped_df` is defined,  please

Comment: I wrote it myself, it's quite basic: 1. Extract the groups (with `attr(df, "group")`) 2. Check the groups for equality 3. Check the ungrouped data for equality.

Comment: OK. Feel free to write a fuller answer, if you want to include that.